# IIS 7 on Windows Azure default configuration not passing through custom authentication header to service running

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, azure, windows-server-2008

I am using a digest like (but not digest) custom authentication scheme where the authentication header field of the http request contains username:encryptedtokendata

I do not have any problems with this scheme on on Windows 7 and Azure emulator. However when I deployed my service to Azure's Windows 2008 Server SP2 my authentication header fails to make it through to my wcf service. It is null.

IIS on Windows 7 & Windows 2008 Server has both anonymous and membership authentications enabled (because i use membership for certain authentications). Every other authentication is disabled.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue for me? I searched stack-overflow and google up and down without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would check and make sure your authentication module is getting installed in Azure and that it is listed correctly in IIS there.  You should be able to remote into the instance and troubleshoot it just like you would on premise.